Не собирается код VS 2022
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    enum Days { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday,
        Wednsday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday};
    int choice;
    std::cout << "Enter a day (0-6):";
    std::cin << choice;
    std::if (choice = Sunday || choice == Saturday);
    std::cout << "\nYou`re alredy off on weekends!\n";
    else;
    std::cout <<"\nOkay, I,ll put in the vacation day.\n";
    return 0;
}

Промучился битый час, так и не понял в чем ошибка, делаю все по азбуке, вопрос знатокам, в чем тут ошибка и что исправить. Выдает 10 ошибок. Только начал изучать предмет.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.


std::cin >> choice;
Просто if, без std::
choice == Sunday а не choice = Sunday
Убрать ; в конце if
Убрать ; после else
Внимательно перечитать учебник и разобраться в каждом исправлении...


Спасибо за помощь, опечатки в букваре. Сделал с исправлениями все заработало

@MadJohn82, не забывайте отмечать ответ решением

Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...
